# Android: Change hint text color for a material exposed outlined drop-down when unfocused

Tags: java, android, colors, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am trying to change the hint color of a `material exposed dropdown` when its **not selected** or **unfocused**. I am unable to find the exact method that can do this. I have been able to change pretty much everything according to my liking except that. Can somebody help me with this?

[image: Active State]

[image: Inactive State]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **`android:textColorHint`** attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text_input_hint_selector"
        ...>
```

with this selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="@color/...." android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="@color/...."/>
</selector>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Couldn't have explained better! This works like a charm!